# Using ConcatRelated() With Variables

Tags: ms-access, vba, concatenation, ms-access-2013

I am attempting to use Allen Brownes ConcatRelated() function in my VBA syntax with a variable.

I keep getting a debug error of

> Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '& varfield &' .

This is the synatx I have in my VBA

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
Public varfield  As String

varfield = [Jersey Number]

sConcat = ConcatRelated(" & varfield & ","[PlayerInfoImport]","playernumber = " & playernumber)
```

What is the appropriate way to write this syntax so it will not throw a debug error?

Comment: `ConcatRelated(varfield, "[PlayerInfoImport]", "playernumber = " & playernumber)` perhaps?

Comment: Too few paramaters, expected 1 error.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
sConcat = ConcatRelated(varfield, "[PlayerInfoImport]", "playernumber = " & playernumber)
```

The first word is a variable, you must not enclose it inside quote if you want to concat it's value.

Make sure you are declaring your variables correctly and your error will go away

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim varfield As String
    Dim sConcat As String
    Dim playernumber As Integer
    playernumber = 1
    varfield = "12345"
    sConcat = ConcatRelated(varfield, "[PlayerInfoImport]", "playernumber = " & playernumber)
    Debug.Print sConcat
End Sub
```

If i declare varfield as variant, i do get your "ByRef argument type mismacth" error.

Comment: That gives an error of too few parameters, exepected 1

Comment: Could you add the ConcatRelated function signature

Comment: I think your variable varfield is not a string, that would be why you get an error.

Comment: varfield is declared as string

Comment: You need to wrap it in quotation marks `varfield  = "[Jersey Number]"`

Comment: @KostasK.- what would be the proper way to quote it?  I thought I was doing it in my OP

Comment: Strings must be enclosed in `"` quotation marks e.g. `"String"` or `"[Jersey Number]"`.

Comment: @GELR - it is a "global" variable that I am using and it is declared As Public varfield String - I also have Option Compare Database
Option Explicit declared at the top of my procedure